# How to get xml Curl Response

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am use curl method to get response from server.
  but when ehco this response it show as simple data.
but in view source it show xml format.

can anybody tell me how to print response as xml

I am using this code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data_tcetra);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
ob_start();
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$xml = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo htmlspecialchars($xml);
```

The actual function you're searching for is called [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/function.htmlspecialchars.php). It converts symbols like `<` to to their entity references `&lt;`.

In my code above, we also need the Output Caching (*ob_**) functions, so that we can prevent the output from directly being sent to the browser. I'd suggest you though that you use the better way in the code below:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === false) {
  // error handling
}
else {
  echo htmlspecialchars($result);
}
```

Comment: "it's not working" is not enough information to help you. Please include error messages and their stack traces.

Comment: As your provided code, i use it but It's give me blank page. No any content showing.